# NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. ReactJS Redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

[image]The complain is from this PropertyAction from Redux

```
const { data } = await axios.get("/api/properties");

dispatch({
  type: actionTypes.GET_PROPERTIES_SUCCESS,
  payload: data,
});
```